# dompdf - blank pages are generated when setting td width - dompdf 0.6.1 v3

Tags: dompdf

I'm trying to create table with three equal columns

**Table width is set to 100%**

When I'm trying to set **width: 33% on TABLE TD** element dompdf generates **1+ blank page(s)** before generates the table. The table generates as expected only those blank pages are present in pdf document.

PDF FILE with width: 33%: http://www.docdroid.net/b5cf/with-width.pdf.html

I need to have equal columns on this table and cant achive it with width="33%" or style="table-layout: fixed" without geting the blank pages befor the table.

The HTML looks like this

```
<table class="outer_tab">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="outer_tr">
            <td valign="top" class="outer_td">
                <table class="inner_tab">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th valign="top" colspan="2">I.</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="inner_td">
                                <span class="separator">Morfologia ogólna</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="inner_td">
                                <span class="lp">1. 
                                    <span style="font-weight: bold;"> HCT </span> - <span class="inner_td_text">Hematokryt</span>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" class="outer_td">
                <table class="inner_tab">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th valign="top" colspan="2">II.</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="inner_td">
                                <span class="separator">Morfologia ogólna</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="inner_td">
                                <span class="lp">1. 
                                    <span style="font-weight: bold;"> HCT </span> - <span class="inner_td_text">Hematokryt</span>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" class="outer_td">
                <table class="inner_tab">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th valign="top" colspan="2">III.</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="inner_td">
                                <span class="separator">Morfologia ogólna</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="inner_td">
                                <span class="lp">1. 
                                    <span style="font-weight: bold;"> HCT </span> - <span class="inner_td_text">Hematokryt</span>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>  
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @page { margin: 1cm; }

    body {
        background-image: url('<?php echo 'module/Application/assets/pdf/images/faktury-tlo-small.png'; ?>');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 20%;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    table.outer_tab, table.inner_tab  { border-spacing: 0; width: 100% }
    table.inner_tab th { text-align: center; background: #BDC0BF; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; padding: 2px 0; }
    td.outer_td { border-top: 1px solid #BDC0BF; border-left: 1px solid #BDC0BF; /*width: 33%;*/ border-bottom: 1px solid #BDC0BF; }
    td.outer_td:last-of-type { border-right: 1px solid #BDC0BF; }
    tr.outer_tr:last-of-type td.outer_td { border-bottom: 1px solid #BDC0BF; }
    span.lp { padding-left: 10px; display: block; }
    span.inner_td_text { /*padding-right: 10px;*/ }
    span.separator { font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px; display: block; }
    .footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; font-size: 11px; }
</style>
```

The line cosing problems is:

```
td.outer_td { border-top: 1px solid #BDC0BF; border-left: 1px solid #BDC0BF; /*width: 33%;*/ border-bottom: 1px solid #BDC0BF; }
```

If in this **td.outer_td has width: 33%** the PDF has blank pages before the table

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?
Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: I suspect you are experiencing this because one of the columns in your document is large enough to run the height of the page. When you specify the column width you are probably affecting the layout just enough that the table cell becomes larger then a page, triggering the [oversized table cell bug](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/98). You can confirm it by removing some text from that column. Unfortunately there's not a good work around right now.

Comment: Dompdf doesn't render floats, nor renders nested/conent-loaded tables accurately. Then how are we supposed to print two pieces of content side by side.